# Routing internet bound traffic from one interface to another

Tags: linux, networking, firewalld

So, my set up is as follows. I have my linux server with firewalld between my access point(AP) and my internet router(IR). My server connects wirelessly to the AP, and with a LAN cable to the IR, and both interfaces are in different networks(AP-192.168.0.1, IR-192.168.178.1). I'd like to know how I would configure a rule to forward internet traffic coming from the wireless interface to the wired interface.

Edit: Additional info: Both networks are /24 netmasks, belong to a custom zone that i created, with no changes made to the default outgoing connection rules.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to have more data about your setup. Depending on zones in your firewall config, assuming firewalld is up and running, assuming both interfaces have 24 netmasks and assuming you have outgoing connections allowed by default rule may be for example :

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-source=192.168.0.0/24 --permanent
```

or

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule 'rule family="ipv4" source address=192.168.0.0/24 accept'
```

Comment: They are both 24 netmasks, and they're in a custom zone that I created, and I didn't change any of the outgoing rules after creating the zone.